# What are my options for replacing or upgrading my window screens?

Tags: windows, screens

I've just bought a house that has older wooden-framed windows. The windows themselves appear to be fine, but the screens for these windows are simple aluminum frames that use the small spring-loaded pegs that fit into holes in the window frame to hold them in. As a result, the screen doesn't have anything close to a flush fit around the edges, so insects are able to crawl in.

I've noticed in some newer houses with vinyl windows that some of the screens sit in a track of sorts so that they can be raised and lowered, and as a result there's no place for insects to get around the edges. Is there any way to get a better-fitting screen for my existing wooden windows? Perhaps a screen uni

Comment: How big is the gap?  Would you be able to install some sort of weather stripping between the window frame and the screen?

Comment: That's a possibility. I've considered a couple of different options, not excluding the possibility of just duct taping the sucker to the window frame ;) I was more interested in seeing if these in-track screens were something that could be added after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [Combination Storm/Screen Window](http://www.screenmobile.com/window-screens/window-weatherizing/combination-storm-screen-windows.aspx), and most hardware stores can order exactly what you want or you can pick through the selection at [The Home Depot: Window Screens](http://www.homedepot.com/Doors-Windows-Screens-Tools-Accessories-Pre-framed-Screens-Window-Screens/h_d1/N-5yc1vZbchj/h_d2/Navigation?catalogId=10053&Nu=P_PARENT_ID&langId=-1&storeId=10051&currentPLP=true&omni=c_Window%20Screens&searchNav=true) is a wide variety of combination storm window/screens to pick from.

Comment: Interesting...I'll have to take a look at this when I'm at the store this weekend. Thanks!